# Unity Juego BreakOut pelota pierde velocidad y direccion

Tags: unity, unity2d

Acabo de terminar un juego estilo BreakOut pero hay un bug en donde en ocasiones la pelota se queda pegada a los bordes del mapa sin direccion ni velocidad tal como se muestra en la captura

Lo que veo es que eso pasa cuando la pelota pierde por completo la trayectoria o la velocidad, pero no he podido solucionar el error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Igual si se requiere mas info del lo mando

https://youtube.com/shorts/s1cEaU3bBF4?feature=share

Mi codigo

```
    void Update()
    {
        currentVelocity = rigidbody2D.velocity;
        if (Mathf.Abs(currentVelocity.y) < 3 && Mathf.Abs(currentVelocity.y) < 3 && GameManager.Instance.ballOnGame)
        {
            velocity = 10;
            rigidbody2D.velocity = Vector2.up * velocity ;
        }
        if (Mathf.Abs(currentVelocity.y) + Mathf.Abs(currentVelocity.y) < 10 && GameManager.Instance.ballOnGame)
        {
            velocity = 10;
            rigidbody2D.velocity = Vector2.up * velocity ;
        }
        if  (velocity <10 && GameManager.Instance.ballOnGame)
        {
            velocity = 10;
            rigidbody2D.velocity = Vector2.up * velocity ;
        }

        if ((Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W) && GameManager.Instance.ballOnGame == false)||(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space) && GameManager.Instance.ballOnGame == false))
        {
            rigidbody2D.velocity = Vector2.up * velocity ;
            transform.parent = null;
            GameManager.Instance.ballOnGame = true;
            rigidbody2D.isKinematic = false;
            rigidbody2D.AddForce(new Vector3(velocity, velocity, 0));
            if (!GameManager.Instance.GameStarted)
            {
                GameManager.Instance.GameStarted = true;

            }
        }
    }
    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.transform.CompareTag("Brick") && superBall)
        {
            rigidbody2D.velocity = currentVelocity;
            return;
        }
        moveDirection=Vector2.Reflect(currentVelocity,collision.GetContact(0).normal);
        if (Mathf.Abs(moveDirection.y) < yMinSpeed)
        {
            moveDirection.y = yMinSpeed*Mathf.Sign(moveDirection.y);
        }
        rigidbody2D.velocity=moveDirection;

        audioController.PlaySfx(bounceSfx);

        if (collision.transform.CompareTag("BottomLimit"))
        {
            if(GameManager.Instance != null)
            {
                GameManager.Instance.PlayerLives--;
                audioController.PlayDie(dieSfx);
                if (GameManager.Instance.PlayerLives > 0)
                {
                    rigidbody2D.velocity = Vector2.zero;
                    transform.SetParent(paddle);
                    transform.localPosition = new Vector2(0, 0.65f);
                    GameManager.Instance.ballOnGame = false;
                }
                
            }
        }
    }
```